# PostgreSQL interactive terminal: passing parameters with single quotes or double quotes - any difference?

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

In a bash script I have the following code:

```
if [ $variable_name == 'NULL' ] ; then 
  variable_name="NULL" ; fi 


psql - h $IP
     -U $NAME
     -n
     -q
     -f some_psql_procedure 
     -v variable_name =$variable_name
```

What's the difference whether I pass a variable with string `'SOME_STRING'` or a variable with string `"SOME_STRING"` to the PostgreSQL interactive terminal?

Does this `if`-statement make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't make any sense.

The difference between single and double quotes is that the shell *interpolates* expressions like `$varname` in double quoted strings, while single quoted strings are left alone.

Comment: by "leaving alone" you mean: the stuff between the single quotes is taken literally?

Comment: Yes sorry for the sloppy expression.